# Show all project source files?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.1

I'm working on an Xcode 6.1 project. The project has two projects, and it looks like so in *Project Navigator*:

```
+ [Xcode Project.xcodeproj]
|
+---- [Common Project.xcodeproj]
|
+---- Applications Folder
      |
      +---- Sub Directory 1
      |
      +---- Sub Directory 2
      |
      +---- Sub Directory 3
```

The app is built from the top level project. `[Common Project.xcodeproj]` is a common framework shared across different projects.

The problem I am having is `[Common Project.xcodeproj]`, which is a full Xcode project, is not displaying any folders or files even though there are about 960 of them. When I build the app, hundreds of files are compiled.

If I drill into the sources and click the `[Common Project.xcodeproj]`, then it opens the top level project again with the same problem above.

How do I have Xcode display the files in an Xcode project when the project is not top level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are filter buttons on the bottom of the project navigator.

You can filter files based on recently opened, source control status changed, and string matching in the name.

If you have all of these unselected, then all the files in the project should be there.

Comment: Damn... that was it. I saw the word `Main` in the box, but did not think any thing of it. I didn't know it was a filter.